# Manipulation of large lists in python

Tags: python, list

Let's say that I have this list with 3 items and every item contains 3 more items:

```
list = [ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9] ]
```

I want to create a 3**2 = 9 list which contains all the combinations of the items, which means

combination of (x,y,z) with x in `[1,4,7]`, y in `[2,5,8]` and z in `[3,6,9]`, so I will use *list comprehension* like this:

```
new_list =[(x,y,z) for x in [1,2,3] for y in [4,5,6] for z in [7,8,9]]
```

This is a "manual" approach. But if I want to use in my code large lists which every time vary in length, let's say a 20D list (20 items and every item contains 20 more items), how can I create a generic type of code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `itertools.product` but the result would be 3<sup>3</sup> = 27 item :

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> lst = [ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9] ]
>>> 
>>> list(product(*lst))
[(1, 4, 7), (1, 4, 8), (1, 4, 9), (1, 5, 7), (1, 5, 8), (1, 5, 9), (1, 6, 7), (1, 6, 8), (1, 6, 9), (2, 4, 7), (2, 4, 8), (2, 4, 9), (2, 5, 7), (2, 5, 8), (2, 5, 9), (2, 6, 7), (2, 6, 8), (2, 6, 9), (3, 4, 7), (3, 4, 8), (3, 4, 9), (3, 5, 7), (3, 5, 8), (3, 5, 9), (3, 6, 7), (3, 6, 8), (3, 6, 9)]
```

Note that when you are dealing with large datasets you don't need to convert the result to list. Since the `product` returns an iterator you can simple loop overt the products and access to items.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for, also you are right about the result, that would be 3**3=27.